# Add an option to a drop down list if a bool is true

Tags: php

I want to add an option to a drop down list if a bool is true, example, if ownsuv = true, it will add it to the drop down list including the other cars he/she owns.
edit: adding code

```
<?
$showgender = true;
if($showgender = true){
<html>
<p>
What is your Gender?
<select name="formGender">
  <option value="">Select...</option>
  <option value="M">Male</option>
  <option value="F">Female</option>
</select>
</p>
</html>
}
 ?>
```

Comment: Could you post some code ?

Comment: We need to see that you have made an effort to see if you can solve your issue yourself rather than someone write it all for you

Comment: I have no idea how I would do this and after googling I can't find exactly what I'm looking for, is this still allowed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php

$showgender = true;
if ($showgender) {
  echo '
  <html>
  <p>
  What is your Gender?
  <select name="formGender">
    <option value="">Select...</option>
    <option value="M">Male</option>
    <option value="F">Female</option>
  </select>
  </p>
  </html>
  ';
}
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could put the `select` element in a variable, like so:

```
$select_element = <<<HTML
<p>
What is your Gender?
<select name="formGender">
  <option value="">Select...</option>
  <option value="M">Male</option>
  <option value="F">Female</option>
</select>
</p>
HTML;
```

Now, if `$showgender` is true, show that `$select_element`, like so:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <h1>Welcome to my wonderful form</h1>
        <form>
<?php
if ($showgender) {
    echo $select_element;
}
?>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: No need to use braces if the conditional statement has a one line suite. Simply just indent the suite.

Answer (score -1):

First of all you will run into PHP errors if you don't add a closing ?> after your if clause:

```
<?php
$showgender = true;
if($showgender == true){
?>
<html>
<p>
What is your Gender?
<select name="formGender">
  <option value="">Select...</option>
  <option value="M">Male</option>
  <option value="F">Female</option>
</select>
</p>
</html>
<?php
}
?>
```

If you want to add an option, just do it like that then:

```
<?php
$showgender = true;
if($showgender == true){
?>
<html>
<p>
What is your Gender?
<select name="formGender">
  <option value="">Select...</option>
  <option value="M">Male</option>
  <option value="F">Female</option>
  <?php if($yourboolean == true) { ?>
  <option value="X">Feel Free</option>
  <?php } ?>
</select>
</p>
</html>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: This is entirely incorrect.

A single = sign is an assignment operator not a comparison operator. Why are you checking if it is equal to true? It is a conditional statement if ($showgender) does the same thing. What you have written now will result in a syntax error.

Comment: Okay this helps a lot more. I just copied the initial version and overlooked this assignment in the first condition. Of course it needs to be either two or three = - depending on what check you want to perform. I will edit that right now.

Comment: By the way assigning a value to a variable returns true so this would not result in a syntax error but always output the select box.